# Navigate between screen React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation-drawer, react-navigation

I have three simple screens: **Login, Dashboard** and **About**.

I want to create a Drawer menu from where I can navigate between the screens. If I am not logged in I want to have the Login screen that gets me to Dashboard where I have the Drawer. There I can click sign out and it gets me back to the Login screen. If I am already logged in I want the first screen to be the Dashboard with drawer included. Furthermore if I click sign out to navigate to Login.

The problem is: After I press the logout button and get back to Login screen. I can t log in anymore ( Dashboard it s still in stack, because if I press the back button it gets me there). And the drawer appears in Login screen also

```
const RootStackLogin = createStackNavigator(
{
  Login: {
    screen: Login,
  },
  Dashboard: {
    screen: Dashboard,
  },
  App: {
    screen: App,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      header:null
    })
  }
},
{
  initialRouteName: 'Login',
}

const RootStackDashboard = createStackNavigator(
{
  Login: Login,
  App: {
    screen: App,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      header:null
    })
  }
},
{
  initialRouteName: 'App',
}
```

This is how the render method from my Splash class looks:

```
if (this.state.isAuth) {
  return (
    <RootStackDashboard/>
  )
}

return (
  <RootStackLogin/>
)
```

And this is my drawer:

```
const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Dashboard: {
    screen: Dashboard,
  },
  Login: {
    screen: Login,
  },
  About: {
    screen: About,
  },
},
{
  contentComponent: CustomContentComponent
})
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: question: if I understood correctly you want to have two different stackNavigators based if the user is logged in or not, right? And then after the logout you want to be redirected to your login screen to be able to login again?

Comment: @kivul, exactly

Comment: @CristiDumitrache check my answer and see if solves your problem

Comment: I'll give you hints 1) You needs nested navigations 2) Use navigate in splash screen 3) Use reset when user logout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is nested navigation, navigate in splash screen and navigate to login when logout.

Let's dive in

1) Nested navigation (Remove Login from Drawer, Add AppDrawerNavigator into RootNavigation)

```js
const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Dashboard: {
    screen: Dashboard,
  },
  About: {
    screen: About,
  },
},
{
  contentComponent: CustomContentComponent
})

const RootNavigation = createStackNavigator({
  Drawer: AppDrawerNavigator,
  Login: Login,
  App: {
    screen: App,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      header:null
    })
  }
},
{
  initialRouteName: 'App',
}
```

2) In `App`'s `componentDidMount()` navigate to appropriate route

```
StackActions.push({
  routeName: this.state.isAuth ? "Drawer" : "Login"
});
```

3) When logout use reset

```
StackActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: "Login" })],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want access to navigate the screens must be you installed two plugins.

> react-navigation
>
> react-native-gesture-handler

Follow this sample code:

```
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";

const MyDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
Home: {
screen: MyHomeScreen,
},
Notifications: {
screen: MyNotificationsScreen,
},
});

const MyApp = createAppContainer(MyDrawerNavigator);
```

check this link : [navigation documentaion](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-based-navigation.html)

Comment: I dont think this is what the question is about

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
if (this.state.isAuth) {
  return (
    <RootStackDashboard/>
  )
}

return (
  <RootStackLogin/>
)
```

Try this:

```
if (this.state.isAuth) {
  navigation.dispatch(StackActions.reset(
    { index: 0, key: null, actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'RootStackDashboard' })] }
  ))
} else {
  navigation.dispatch(StackActions.reset(
    { index: 0, key: null, actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'RootStackLogin' })] }
  ))
}
```

You can see more here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-actions.html

But basically the reset action will wipe the whole navigation state and replace it with something else defined by you.

Also dont forget the import:

```
import { NavigationActions, StackActions } from 'react-navigation';
```